# Проблема с закрывающим тегом "<?php"?

Tags: php

[image: Результат отправки формы]

[image: Форма]

Всем привет!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?
Появляются символы под строкой "Заказ обработан.".

Код PHP документа:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Автозапчасти от Игоря - Результаты заказа</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Автозапчасти от Игоря</h1>
<h2>Результаты заказа</h2>  
<?php echo '<p>Заказ обработан.</p>';?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Код формы:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>orderform</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<meta name="orderform" content="Пример создания формы заказа"> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form action = "processorder.php" method = "post">
<table border = "0">
<tr bgcolor = "#cccccc">
<td width = "150">Товар</td>    <td width = "15">Количество</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Покрышки</td>     <td align = "center"><input type = "text" name = "tireqty" size = "3" maxlength = "3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Масло</td>   <td align = "center"><input type = "text" name = "oilqty" size = "3" maxlength = "3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Свечи зажигания</td>  <td align = "center"><input type = "text" name = "sparkqty" size = "3" maxlength = "3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan = "2" align = "center"><input type = "submit" value = "Отправить заказ" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Спасибо всем! Я забыл, что нужно прописывать Localhost... и т.д. Я просто кликнул мышью по html файлу в папке, думал, что он сам обратится к php документу по всем правилам. Вобщем, стормозил я... Спасибо всем.

Comment: Может не поддерживается php или это обычный файл на ПК без всякой поддержки? Для таких целей Denwer можно скачать.

Comment: Я не пробовал, но, казалось бы, должен и открывающий быть виден,

Comment: @splash58, нет, не виден. https://jsfiddle.net/seutbn0k/

Comment: вот так виднее - https://jsfiddle.net/seutbn0k/1/ . А я поленился проверять :)

Comment: А почему вы свои файлы открываете мимо сервера?

Comment: Visman, спасибо! Я забыл, что нужно прописывать Locallhost... и т.д. Я просто кликнул мышью по html файлу в папке, думал, что он сам обратится к php документу по всем правилам. Вобщем, стормозил я... Спасибо всем.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по строке запроса, вы открываете свой файл html не через сервер, поэтому он отображает теги php как текст. Чтобы отрабатывал php код поместите это файл в папку сервера, и откройте его через сервер, что-то типа http://localhost/index.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Судя по всему у вас вообще не отрабатывает php код. Открывающий тег php съедается html. Чтобы проверить это, просто откройте исходник получившейся страницы в браузере и посмотрите "сгенерированный" html код - сразу все станет понятно
2. Совершенно не ясен смысл конструкции `<?php echo '<p>Заказ обработан.</p>';?>` -  не проще ли сразу вывести html код если вы его все равно уже отображаете?

Answer (score 0):

1. Файл должен быть с расширением PHP.
2. Он должен находиться на сервере с поддержкой PHP и исполняться через сервер.

Comment: Файл не обязательно должен иметь расширение `.php`, все зависит от настроек Apache (см. директивы `AddHandler` и `AddType`).

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте поставить пробел между выводимой строкой и закрывающим тегом

```
<?php echo '<p>Заказ обработан.</p>';  ?>
```

Comment: странно, если поможет :)

Answer (score -1):

А у тебя php код на сервере хоть выполняется? 
Если у тебя php файл..
Сделай так..

```
<?php
echo <<<HTML
<html>
<head>
<title>Автозапчасти от Игоря - Результаты заказа</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Автозапчасти от Игоря</h1>
<h2>Результаты заказа</h2>
<p>Заказ обработан.</p>
</body>
</html>
HTML;
```